# How to solve the situation that the appSerivce is killed by the system?

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

My WinForm application and uwp communicate through appService and implement appService functionality in app.xaml.cs, but the system will kill appService at any time, and how to solve this problem. 
This is the code in WinForm:

```
var appService = new AppServiceConnection();

// Here, we use the app service name defined in the app service provider's Package.appxmanifest file in the <Extension> section.
appService.AppServiceName = AppServiceName; 

// Use Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.FamilyName within the app service provider to get this value.
appService.PackageFamilyName = PackageFamilyName; 

var status = await appService.OpenAsync();
if (status != AppServiceConnectionStatus.Success)
{
    textBox2.Text = "fail";
    return;
}
```

This is the code in uwp:

```
protected override async void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnBackgroundActivated(args);
    IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance = args.TaskInstance;
    AppServiceTriggerDetails appService = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as AppServiceTriggerDetails;
    appServiceDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    taskInstance.Canceled += OnAppServicesCanceled;
    appServiceConnection = appService.AppServiceConnection;
    appServiceConnection.RequestReceived += OnAppServiceRequestReceived;
    appServiceConnection.ServiceClosed += AppServiceConnection_ServiceClosed;


    //timer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer((t) => {
    //    callCount++;
    //}, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));

}
```

Comment: Instead of deleting the question and asking it again → *If you’ve asked a good question, edited it with status and progress updates, and still are not receiving answers, you can draw attention to your question by placing a bounty on it.* To learn more, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). Also since *A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked*, it's better for you to keep the old question.

Comment: I would solve it in the same way you handle it when both programs aren't running at the same time: By displaying something like "other side not available" or "communication error" or something like that, since you can't either rely on both of them being available. Expect the failure and inform the user accordingly.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much

Comment: @Alejandro Can't prevent the system from killing appService？

Comment: @Values That's not within your control, plain and simple. You control what happens inside your programs, but not when they run or what happens in the rest of the system. You cannot even control that both of your programs are alive together, the user may well kill one of them. The very same situation if your program requires internet access, you cannot *ensure* you have it, you just try to use it. And be ready to handle failure gracefully.

Comment: @Alejandro I think about other ways. Thank you.

Comment: I solved this problem in other ways. Although I can't solve the problem that appService was killed by the system, I added a judgment in the WinForm application and reconnected if it was found that appService did not exist. Please let me know if there is a better way than this, thank you.

Comment: Is your Winform EXE and the UWP EXE in the same app package?

Comment: @Stefan Wick MSFT  WinForm and uwp are two completely independent applications

Comment: In that case the expected behavior is that the AppService connection will be closed after 30sec. If that's what you are seeing it is currently expected.